# Getting smooth curve with gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I'm not getting smooth curve on gnuplot.

This is my code:

```
set style line 3 lc rgb '#09ad00' lt 1 lw 1.5 #green
set style line 1 lc rgb '#0060ad' lt 1 lw 2  #blue 
set style line 2 lc rgb '#dd181f' lt 1 lw 2  #red
plot [-1:1] f1(x) with line ls 3,f2(x) with line ls 1,f1(x)+f2(x) with line ls 2
```

I'm getting this plot

[image: zig-zag curve no smooth curve]

while I'm expecting this type of curve

[image: smooth curve no zig-zag curve]

Comment: Add a line `set samples 200`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't shown what your particular functions are, but this is almost certainly a sampling problem.  Gnuplot doesn't really draw curves for functions - it actually computes the functions at multiple points and connects them with straight lines, similarly to what would happen if you were plotting a data file.  The number of points that it computes is user settable.

Suppose that I do `plot sin(x)` and see this:
[image: Jagged sine curve]

Here the sampling rate is set pretty low.  We can look at the individual points in order to see what is going on.

[image: Jagged sine curve with points]

In order to improve this, I need to increase the sampling rate by using the `set samples ?` command.  The default is 100 (in 5.0 patch level 6).  Depending on how rapidly the function changes, higher values may be needed.  I usually set it to around 1000 with `set samples 1000`.  This changes the graph to

[image: Smooth sine curve]

which produces a much nicer smooth curve.  Again, this is just a bunch of points connected by straight lines, but when there are a lot of these, it looks like a smooth continuous curve.

We can look at the individual points again (using a sampling rate of 100 as 1000 is too many to clearly see the points)

[image: Smooth sine curve with points]

We can also see here that there is not much difference between the graph with 1000 points and 100 points.  In the case of a sine curve, 100 is enough to see a smooth graph, but with a faster changing curve, we may need more.

The `set samples` command takes (optionally) two values, but the second value is only used for 3d plots.  You can find out more with the `help samples` command.

Comment: Gnuplot's default (relatively low) number of samples is possibly related to the age of the program (read SLOW computers).  I recommend to place a `set samples 1001` command in `$HOME/.gnuplot`, also as a rule of thumb the number of samples could be around `30*number of maxima`. Very good answer.

Comment: @gboffi I haven't looked at the historical values to see if that default has changed from earlier versions, but yes, you are almost certainly right about why it is so low.